# rewrite rule on codeigniter doesn't go

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

After many time, I really don't understand why my rewrite rule doesn't ok. I use CI framework and I need to go to controller /show/place/1 when I set /france in URI.

This is my code :

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    SetEnv PHP_VER 5
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|img\/|css\/|js\/|favicon.ico)

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [PT,L]

    RewriteRule ^france$ index.php/show/place/1 [PT,L]
```

Someone can help me please?

Answer (score 2):

It is much more convinient to use Codeigniter URI Routing for this, see http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: Thank you for your solution but how can I do if I need to generate uri dynamically?

Comment: Codeigniter routing system supports wildcards. Please read provided reference for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try chancing order of your rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
SetEnv PHP_VER 5
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|img\/|css\/|js\/|favicon.ico)

RewriteRule ^france$ index.php/show/place/1 [PT,L]

RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php/).*)$ /index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

Comment: Thanks but I already did it but I had an Internal server error.

Comment: I always have 404 error. I'm really lost, I used this redirection type with many others projects and It's working fine. does It possible it is because of my CI config?

Comment: Yes it appears that problem is due to CI routing mechanism. Try putting `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'ORIG_PATH_INFO';` in your `application/config/config.php`

Comment: Now, I don't have any errors but I always rediricted to the home.

Comment: What I meant to say is change `$config['uri_protocol']` to `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'ORIG_PATH_INFO';` in your `application/config/config.php`

Answer (score 0):

take a look at URI Routing Class http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/routing.html
for your question here is a snippet
Go to /application/config/routes.php
and add this:

```
$route['france'] = 'show/place/1';
```

in .htaccess file just remove the index.php

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|img|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I already found what to do for "France" with your help in  http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/routing.html but my question is : How can I use routes.php if I need to write uri dynamically? (for ex: each time someone insert a country on DB)

Comment: then you must add a method that fetches the countries

Answer (score 0):

Have you also set the config.php $config['index_page'] to blank?

change `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`

to ->  `$config['index_page'] = '';`